# Windows command line string parsing: folder and filename in string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a quick way to get the filename and last folder from a full file path (string) in Windows command line?

I would expect for input -> results:

```
"c:\test\1\2\test.txt" -> "2", "test.txt"  
"c:\test\1\2\3\a.txt" -> "3", "a.txt"  
"c:\test\0\b.txt" -> "0", "b.txt"  
"c:\c.txt" -> "", "c.txt"
```

I've been banging my head at this using FOR /F but since the full path can be any length, I can't figure it out.

Comment: If you have a solution, it should go in the answer section.

Comment: @Casey The solution is in the accepted answer, I just elaborated on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for %I in (c:\test\1\2\3\a.txt) do set path=%~pI
for %I in (c:\test\1\2\3\a.txt) do set file=%~nxI
set pth2=%path:~0,-1%
for %I in (%pth2%) do set lastdir=%~nxI
echo %file% %lastdir%
```

The [Windows Command Line Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) is your friend.

Comment: Indeed, much more helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Here is another link to have under your pillow when writing these ugly dos code: http://www.computerhope.com/msdos.htm, see the section on the SET command for info on how I used it in line #3

Comment: Great! Fore future reference, I found [http://ss64.com/nt/](http://ss64.com/nt/) to be helpful as well.

Answer (score 4):

FOR/TOKENS would work if the path were reversed so what about;

```
echo off
set apath=c:\test\1\2\3\a.txt

call :reverse "%apath%"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\\" %%a in ("%reverse.result%") do set afile=%%a&set adir=%%b

call :reverse "%apath%"
set apath = %reverse.result%

call :reverse "%afile%"
set afile= %reverse.result% 

rem handle no dir;
if "%adir:~0,1%"==":" set adir=

echo File: %afile%
echo Dir:  %adir%
goto:eof  

:reverse
  set reverse.tmp=%~1
  set reverse.result=
  :reverse.loop
    set reverse.result=%reverse.tmp:~0,1%%reverse.Result%
    set reverse.tmp=%reverse.tmp:~1,999%
    if not "%reverse.tmp%"=="" goto:reverse.loop
goto:eof
eof:
```

For

```
File: a.txt
Dir:  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @deStrangis' answer, here's the solution I came up with:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

CALL :get_path "C:\test\1\2\3\a.txt"

GOTO last

:get_path
:: get file path
SET _path=%~p1
:: get file name and extension
SET _name=%~nx1
:: remove trailing backslash from path
SET _path=%_path:~0,-1%
:: trim path
CALL :trim_path %_path%
:: output
ECHO %_path% %_name%
GOTO :eof

:trim_path
:: get file name from a path returns the last folder
SET _path=%~n1
GOTO :eof

:last
ECHO ON
```